# Issue in html code for redirect user to url after is logged

Tags: html

Hi I’m html learner and I have an issue with my code but I don’t know what’s the problem

The prob is weird , when i enter the right pass in only have my alert « Le mot de passe est correct » but the page is just reload and not move to `https://mycool-url.com`

This is a simple html code it’s for learn password

```html
  <title>Authentification</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <p class="sign" align="center">Veuillez vous identifier</p>
    <form class="login">
      <input class="pass" type="password" align="center" id="password" placeholder="Mot de Passe" type="password" name="pswrd">
      <input class="submit" align="center" type="submit" onclick="checkPassword()" value="Login" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    function checkPassword() {
      if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'ZhFAIHhyRvBaZ') {
        alert('Mot de passe correct')
        location.replace('https://www.mycool-url.com');
      } else {
        alert('Mot de passe incorrect');
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: _"HTML code"_ You mean JavaScript?

Comment: The behaviour you're witnessing is the expected behaviour of a submit button inside a form. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit#using_submit_buttons

Comment: For what it is worth, your HTML is malformed.  You are missing the open `<head>` tag-- _that_ I assume was probably just missed in your copy/paste.  BUT-- you also have an extraneous closing `</script>` tag.  You should consider running your markup through a validator, as malformed markup can cause all sorts of strange, difficult to debug problems.  Think of it as the foundation of your code building-- it holds everything else up, so you want to make sure its right.

Answer (score 0):

The form is submitting.  If you don't want to submit a form, change the button type from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`:

```
<input class="submit" align="center" type="button" onclick="checkPassword()" value="Login" />
```

If you're not using a "form" at all, you can even just remove the `<form>` element entirely, which would prevent accidental form submission.

As an aside, it's also worth noting that any user can see the "password" or go directly to the target URL so this authentication mechanism doesn't secure anything.

Answer (score 0):

The form is submitting each time. If you don't want to submit the form, you can use the following things for prevent form submission in your cause.

1. ```
   <input class="submit" align="center" type="submit" onclick="checkPassword(); return false;" value="Login"/>
   ```
2. Change the javascript function checkPassword() to return false all the time.

   ```
    function checkPassword(){
     if(document.getElementById('password').value == 'ZhFAIHhyRvBaZ'){
       alert('Mot de passe correct');
       window.location.href='https://www.mycool-url.com';

     } else {
       alert('Mot de passe incorrect');
       return false;
    }
     return false;
   }
   ```

and call it in onclick like this onclick="return checkPassword();"

```
 <input class="submit" align="center" type="submit" onclick="return checkPassword()" value="Login"/>
```

It will also prevent the form from submitting.

Answer (score -1):

Replace  `location.replace('https://www.mycool-url.com');` by `window.location.replace("https://www.mycool-url.com");`

Comment: How does this help?